# How to stop execution process in MVC 5 with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What line of code do I need in the `TODO` section?

My application code is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Override onAuthorization filter is use for authorization use request.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filterContext"></param>

protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    AuthorizationManager authorizationManager = new AuthorizationManager();

    string FilePath = Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath);

    if (!authorizationManager.IsAuthorized(_userSession, FilePath))
    {
        RedirectToControllers(ControllerHelper.Controller.ACCOUNT, ControllerHelper.Controller.Action.ACCOUNT_LOGIN);

        //TODO:
        // 1. Need to stop execution process from here. 
        // 2. No need to execute any line of code from here.
        // I have tested return/Break not working here.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal?  Do you want to exit the `OnAuthorization` function? Or do you want to end the entire `Response`?

Comment: Actually, When i click any links in my application, each and every link check this person is authorized or not for this clicked link. If user is not authorized for this and then user redirect to log-in page . Its working fine but controls are execute to current event.  For example:(If user is not authorize but click on register page user fill the data in database and then redirect to login page.) I hope you understand my issues.

Comment: I'm sorry Anil, I do not understand.

Comment: @Dan-o, How to end the entire Response?

Comment: `Response.End` usually does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `RedirectToControllers` to return an ActionResult then set the  filterContext.Result .

```
//filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/login");

filterContext.Result =  RedirectToControllers(ControllerHelper.Controller.ACCOUNT,  ControllerHelper.Controller.Action.ACCOUNT_LOGIN);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `break` to get out of the `if`?

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    AuthorizationManager authorizationManager = new AuthorizationManager();

    string FilePath = Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath);

    if (!authorizationManager.IsAuthorized(_userSession, FilePath))
    {
        RedirectToControllers(ControllerHelper.Controller.ACCOUNT, ControllerHelper.Controller.Action.ACCOUNT_LOGIN);

        break; // use this
        return; // or this
        // 1. Need to stop excution process from here. 
        // 2. No need to excute any line of code from here.
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry dear, Its not helpful for this issues. Its only for enclosing loop out break.

Comment: What do you mean? It only works on loops (for/while)? It should break out of your `if`. Anyway, you can always use `return` to quit the method

Comment: try adding some return type and then return anything (although i believe it's unnecessary)

Comment: Here  break/return not working. I don't want to add any unnecessary code here.

Comment: Well, im out of ideas. I'm pretty sure return will work